# Is the definition of "limit of function" incomplete?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function) the definition of limit of a function $f$ such that it assigns an output $f(x)$ to every input $x$ is given as follows:

> We say that the function has a limit $L$ at an input $p$, if $f(x)$ gets
> closer and closer to $L$ as $x$ moves closer and closer to $p$.

But I have a problem with it; If $L$ (for concrete example say $5$) is chosen as limit of the function then can't $L-0.1$ ($4.9$) or $L-1$ ($4$) or $L+1$ ($6$) ***also*** be chosen as limit?

Let me explain what I mean.

If value of "input" is made to approach $p$ then, as given, the output will also approach $L$, ***and also*** $L-0.1$, $L-1$..... so what makes us choose only $L$ as the "limit"?

There is no special, explicit property, seems to be, mentioned which allows us to choose $L$ as the ***only*** "limit" and disregard other values(or does it?) like the fix difference between output, for given input, and the limit .

Comment: You are misunderstanding the meaning of the term "closer and closer": it means the distance between the values becomes *arbitrarily small* and that rules out what you are asking. If a function's values differ from $L$ by an *arbitrarily small* amount when $x$ is sufficiently close to $p$, they can't also differ from $L-0.1$ by an arbitrarily small amount, or even by an amount less than $0.1/2$: the numbers $L$ and $L-0.1$ differ by $0.1$, so no number is within (say) $0.01$ of both $L$ and $L-0.1$.

Comment: Consider the sequence of numbers $(1/2)^n$: 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, and so on.  The values of this sequence get "closer and closer" to 0. If you insist they are also getting "closer and closer" to $-35$ then you are missing an essential aspect of what "closer and closer" means: the distance between the terms and the supposed limit (which is $0$, *not* $-35$) should be getting arbitrarily small.

Comment: @KCd I am not sure  that the OP misunderstands the meaning of 'closer and closer', I think this Wiki statement is too imprecise..

Comment: @ How *arbitrarily small* should the distance between the output, for a given input, and the supposed limit should be? $0.00001$ may be? In this sense that is what the question really is! The definition doesn't tell by what *value* should the limit and the output must be closer(a property)? Hence incomplete.

Comment: That's not the definition, it is an _informal_ definition (the sentence you report begins with "Informally,...".

Comment: This is not a definition of limit, it is an informal description. Taking an informal description of what a limit is very seriously and literally isn't going to be productive. You'd do better to focus on the formal definition.

Comment: @MatthewTowers but similar definition is given in my book also, for the sake of universal reference I linked Wikipedia, so does that mean the books definition is also informal? So what is formal definition? And how does that solves the problem?

Comment: No fixed positive number is arbitrarily small: being arbitrarily small means the variable  can be chosen to be smaller than *any predetermined positive value* and something happens.  The number .0000000001 is not "arbitrarily small".  Woild you say .0000001 tends to 0? Nope. You ultimately need to look at actual definitions of concepts, not handwavy informal discussions.  Read the rigorous definition of a limit in an analysis book, or search for "rigorous definition of limits".

Comment: Anything that looks like that is an informal description. The formal definition is the one with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ which you can also find in the wiki article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a function $f$ and a limit point $p$ are given, then the function limit itself $\lim\limits_{x \to p}f(x)$ cannot be chosen - the function limit, if it exists, is uniquely determined by the function itself and the point $p$ to which the variable tends.

Let me say, also, that all these words "tends", "gets closer", "closer and closer" are some kind of mathematical sleng - more good is to think about formal definition:
$$\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, \forall x, 0<|x-p|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L| < \varepsilon$$
so existence of limit is holding of inequality in appropriate conditions: "$x$ tends to $p$", "$x$ get closer to $p$" means first inequality and "$f(x)$ get closer to $L$", "$f(x)$ tends to $L$" means second.

Comment: How do we determine the limit, if it exists?

Comment: @HiterDean. Added to answer formal definition for $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ case.

Comment: @Matthew Towers. Thanks. Fixed. I'm afraid to scare OP with a lot of quantifiers and am waiting for his questions on the formal definition.

Comment: you are right I am really scared! I don't understand anything of your formal definition. I have searched for ' rigorous definition of limit ' on internet and found that it is something beyond my current "limit of understanding mathematical concepts". I will have to accept this informal definition, for now.

Comment: @HiterDean. This is, imho, one of the greatest sentences in history - polished and refined over the years and the work of many people. But it is better to think about it and not about many explanations produced from it. So, feel free, please, ask any time any question if/when they will arise at you.

Comment: Are $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ real numbers?

Comment: do you have some recommendations for good calculus books ie which explain why and how new concepts are introduced such as the concept of limit?

Comment: Yes for first question, when we consider $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, though definition can be expanded up to general, so called, topological spaces. For second question Rudin W. Principles of mathematical analysis, Michael Spivak - Calculus are classical sources. There is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118925/what-book-are-good-to-learn-about-limits-and-continuity-for-the-first-time on this site, but may be worth to set this as separate question one more time.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer gives the definition in formal mathematical symbols, but I would like to emphasize two things.

First, it is not necessary to understand those formal mathematical symbols at first, you can probably learn the meaning of limit more easily and effectively when the definition is written out in ordinary language, in this case in the English language, with just a few inequalities

- For every real number $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a real number $\delta > 0$ such that for every real number $x$, if $0 < |x-p| < \delta$ then $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.

Second, real understanding comes when you are asked to use this definition: either proving a particular limit formula; or applying some limit formula that is already known to be true, and using it to prove something else.

So let me go just a little bit further and explain generally how you can think of the process of proving a limit formula.

If $f(x)$, and $p$, and $L$ are given to you, and if you are asked to prove that $L$ is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $p$, here is what you have to actually do in order to prove it:

1. Let a real number $\epsilon > 0$ be given.
2. You must *find* an appropriate real number $\delta > 0$ and, using it, you must prove the implication: "if $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$".

To really see this process in action on an intuitive level, I like to think of this as a challenge game.

Your adversary presents you with $\epsilon$, perhaps with an exact value like $\epsilon = .01$. And then the adversary says to you "I bet you can't make $|f(x)-L| < .01$, no matter **how close** $x$ is to $p$!!!"

So you take the challenge: using the given formula for $f(x)$, and the given value of $L$, and the actual numerical value $\epsilon = .01$ that the adversary gave you, you first figure out an actual numerical value of $\delta > 0$ (it might be as simple as solving an inequality). Then, using that value of $\delta$, you prove that if $0 < |x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<.01$.

You show this to the adversary who then says, with a pout, "Pshaw! That was too easy. I bet you can't do it with $\epsilon = .0001$!"

So you take up the challenge again: using the given formula for $f(x)$ and the given value of $L$, you figure out a value of $\delta > 0$, and you use it to prove that if $0 < |x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<.0001$.

Then your adversary says "You think you're so smart, here's the ultimate challenge. I bet you can't do it with $\epsilon = .0000000000000000000001$!"

By then you are losing your patience, and so you ignore this *particular* value of $\epsilon$, and instead you proceed like this: using just the symbol $\epsilon$ and the assumption that $\epsilon > 0$, you find a **formula** for $\delta > 0$, expressed in terms of $\epsilon$. Perhaps you find the formula using your previous experience with two particular numerical values of $\epsilon$; perhaps you find it by a more complicated mathematical process of solving the inequality $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$. One way or another, using that formula for $\delta$, you then go on and use it to prove that if $0 < |x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

And your adversary disappears in a puff of smoke.

---

So, how might this whole adversarial process be described on an intuitive level? Perhaps something like this:

> We can force $f(x)$ to be close to $L$ as we are asked to, by taking $x$ as close to $p$ as we like.

Or, in even fewer words, like this (i.e. like the Wikipedia quote):

> $f(x)$ gets closer and closer to $L$, as $x$ gets closer and closer to $p$.

However, I hope that by now you can see that this is *not* a full and proper mathematical definition: without all of the quantifiers and absolute values and inequalities in their proper positions, this intuitive definition does not actually tell you what you have to do to prove or to apply limit formulas.

In order to acheive that, all of that "closer and closer" stuff has to be formalized with correct mathematical expressions using quantifiers, absolute values, and inequalities.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing the importance of definition in English (or whatever language of instruction is being used) over a sequence of logical symbols.